# Merging multple text files from folder to create a dataframe, with string operation

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, file

I have 82 text files in a folder that look like this:

```
Comment: 
Version: 2.3 [1.5.7248]
File Name: C:\Users\RS-8800sn1320\Documents\SpectralEvolution\SR-8800_19A1320\2021_Feb_17\SR-8800_SN19A1320_IRRAD_Swansea_00001.sed
Instrument: SR-8800_SN19A1320 [3]
Detectors: 512,256,256
Measurement: DIRECT_ENERGY
Date: 02/17/2021,02/17/2021
Time: 15:45:35.20,15:45:35.20
Temperature (C): 33.87,8.88,-5.57,33.87,8.88,-5.57
Battery Voltage: 7.70,7.70
Averages: 10,10
Integration: 7,50,30,7,50,30
Dark Mode: AUTO,AUTO
Foreoptic: FIBR15 {RADIANCE}, FIBR15 {RADIANCE}
Radiometric Calibration: RADIANCE
Units: W/m^2/sr/nm
Wavelength Range: 350,2500
```

From all files in the folder, I would like to extract a data frame that has the index names as the words before the colon (:) (which are the same for all files), and the rest of the columns contain the remaining information in the form of a string.

I've gotten this far:

```
path = r"mypath" 

all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.txt")

meta_df = []

df = pd.read_fwf(filename,  header = None, nrows=24)
     
     df['Metadata'] = df[0].str.split(':').str[0]
     
     df.set_index('Metadata', inplace=True)
     
     meta_df.append(df[0])
```

But it just creates a data frame with lists and I can't cut the part after the colon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load your data "manually", using `str.split` and then feed the data to DataFrame. For example:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd


path = r'.'
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.txt")

all_data = []
for filename in all_files:
    with open(filename, 'r') as f_in:
        row = {}
        for line in f_in:
            line = line.strip().split(':', maxsplit=1)
            if len(line) != 2:
                continue
            row[line[0]] = line[1]
        if row:
            all_data.append(row)


df = pd.DataFrame(all_data).T
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                                                                         0                                      1
Comment                                                                                                          
Version                                                     2.3 [1.5.7248]                                    2.4
File Name                 C:\Users\RS-8800sn1320\Documents\SpectralEvol...                     C:\Something other
Instrument                                           SR-8800_SN19A1320 [3]                                 SR-XXX
Detectors                                                      512,256,256                           512,256,2564
Measurement                                                  DIRECT_ENERGY                          DIRECT_ENERGY
Date                                                 02/17/2021,02/17/2021                  02/17/2021,02/17/2021
Time                                               15:45:35.20,15:45:35.20                15:45:35.20,15:45:35.20
Temperature (C)                          33.87,8.88,-5.57,33.87,8.88,-5.57      33.87,8.88,-5.57,33.87,8.88,-5.57
Battery Voltage                                                  7.70,7.70                              7.70,7.70
Averages                                                             10,10                                  10,10
Integration                                                7,50,30,7,50,30                        7,50,30,7,50,30
Dark Mode                                                        AUTO,AUTO                              AUTO,AUTO
Foreoptic                             FIBR15 {RADIANCE}, FIBR15 {RADIANCE}   FIBR15 {RADIANCE}, FIBR15 {RADIANCE}
Radiometric Calibration                                           RADIANCE                               RADIANCE
Units                                                          W/m^2/sr/nm                            W/m^2/sr/nm
Wavelength Range                                                  350,2500                               350,2500
```